# when we click on back then front should be open on click event

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to flip a div on click event, and when I click on div again it should flip back to the original. but as of now its working on mouseleave event only and I want to do on click event of jquery.

For this I tried this:-

```js
$('.flip').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function() {
    //$(this).removeClass('flipped');
  });
  return true;
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.flip .card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.flip .card .face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.flip .card .front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flip .card .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  background: blue;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="face front">Front</div>
    <div class="face back">Back</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Its working on mouseleave event but I want to do on click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead of add/remove class. This will toggle `.flipped` class 'on/off' when you click on the `.flip`

```js
 $('.flip').click(function() {
   $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped')
 });
```

```css
body {
    background: #ccc;
 }
.flip {
   -webkit-perspective: 800;
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 50px auto;
  }
 .flip .card.flipped {
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  .flip .card {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  }
 .flip .card .face {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
 }
 .flip .card .front {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .flip .card .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    background: blue;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="face front">Front</div>
    <div class="face back">Back</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can replicate this behavior by checking if the card has class `flipped` -> remove it, if not -> add it

```
 $('.flip').click(function() {
   const card =  $(this).find('.card')
   card.hasClass('flipped') ? card.removeClass('flipped') : card.addClass('flipped');
  })
```

Comment: @Mangita glad i could help. If this worked for you please rate & accept my answer. Thanks :D

Comment: Hello Mihai, I have one Problem, When I apply this code for a particular element its not working

Comment: @Mangita You had a few problems. 1. you used 2 clicked functions ( don't know why ) . 2. You had only one `flip-action` on the front but not on the back. And you need to remove backface-visibility from `.card.flipped`. See here -> http://jsfiddle.net/L9q85uva/

Comment: If I removed  backface-visibility from .card.flipped then its not working on Safari brawser

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately i cannot test on Safari. There must be a work around.  Is there a reason why you didn't make the click event on the `.flip` and you wanted to make it on the `flip-action` ?

Comment: actually i have number of div using the flip class and there is a link inside of all those divs flip_action. so i want just click  one particular div and want to  flip  on that main div (.flip)

Comment: Its working on all browser except for  safari , In safari its showing blank div on back that why I used  backface-visibility:hidden